# ValueError: You are trying to merge on datetime64[ns, UTC] and object columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following two pandas data frames `df1` and `df2`. Both of them have datetime column:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

np.random.seed(0)
rng = pd.date_range('2015-02-24', periods=5, freq='T')

list=[]
for i in range(len(rng)):
    r=random.randint(1,100)
    if r not in list: list.append(str(r))

df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, 'Id': list, 'Val1': np.random.randn(len(rng))})
df1.head()


                 Date  Id      Val1
  2015-02-24 00:00:00  96 -0.968980
  2015-02-24 00:01:00  31  0.591243
  2015-02-24 00:02:00  58 -0.782776
  2015-02-24 00:03:00  81 -0.444233
  2015-02-24 00:04:00  73 -0.345186

df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, 'Id': list, 'Val2': np.random.randn(len(rng))})
df2.head()
```

Then I want to merge them as shown below:

```
df3 = df1[['Id', 'Date']]\
    .groupby('Id')\
    .agg('max')\
    .merge(df2, on=['Id', 'Date'], how='left')
```

But I get the error:

> ValueError: You are trying to merge on datetime64[ns, UTC] and object
>   columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Expected output:

```
                 Date  Id      Val2
  2015-02-24 00:00:00  96  2.965560
  2015-02-24 00:01:00  31  5.593345
  2015-02-24 00:02:00  58  11.78276
  2015-02-24 00:03:00  81 -0.444234
  2015-02-24 00:04:00  73 -0.322334
```

Please consider that this is a simplified reproduction of my real code. In my real code I only have `merge` operation that fails with the same message. The rest of the code is used to reproduce the needed data formats.

Comment: what does `df1.query('Val1")` give you? What are you trying to get by that query?

Comment: @QuangHoang: Sorry for confusion. I made a mistake in my question. Please see an update.

Comment: works on my computer. You should check both Date columns are datetime type.

Comment: @QuangHoang: I tried to reproduce the error that I get on my real data set. Please add `str(r)` in `list` creation loop as I wrote in my last update. In this case, if you copy-paste the code, it will give an error.

Comment: Also, using `list` as variable is a horrible idea.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: @QuangHoang: It's not exactly my real code. It's the reproduction code. In my real code I only have the `merge` operation that gives exactly the same error as in this example.

Comment: @Arn: The expected output is that it works:) Well, I want to select the max date per `Id` and merge `df1` with `df2` to get columns `[Date, Id, Val2]`.

Comment: Still, you shouldn't put that in your example. On the other note, it works still. One of you datetime has different timezone, convert it with `pd.to_datetime(..., utc=True)`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df3 = df1[['Id', 'Date']].groupby('Id').agg('max')
```

Then:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df3, df2)
```

Produces:

```
>>> df3
                 Date  Id      Val2
0 2015-02-24 00:03:00  12 -0.103219
1 2015-02-24 00:04:00  24  0.410599
2 2015-02-24 00:02:00  32 -0.151357
3 2015-02-24 00:01:00  41  0.950088
4 2015-02-24 00:00:00  46 -0.977278
```

Comment: You may do `df3 = pd.merge(df1[['Id', 'Date']].groupby('Id').agg('max'), df2)`

Comment: In my real data set I still get the error "You are trying to merge on datetime64[ns, UTC] and object columns"... Can I show how to use pd.concat instead of merge?

Comment: Or maybe join? Not sure what is going on with merge

Comment: There should be `reset_index()`, no?